# SOQL TYPEOF Enabling

Tags: soql, polymorphic

I getting an error from FormTitan (for creating forms with connection to salesforce).

> SOQL TYPEOF expressions are not supported for API versions less than
>   46.0 .

I saw that my API version on my sandbox is 46.0.

How can I enable `TYPEOF` functionality? Is there a way to enable it without creating a case to salesforce?

Comment: FormTitan seems to be a managed package, maybe their classes are not on version 46.0

Comment: This is not through AppExchange.. It is an external website which has a connection to SF with some API

Comment: Could you share the query resulting the error?

Comment: Hi Raul, I don't have the query because it happens behind the scenes in FormTitan.
But I asked it from them and while they will provide the query I will post it here.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [`TYPEOF` documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm):

> TYPEOF is currently available as a Developer Preview as part of the
>   SOQL Polymorphism feature. For more information on enabling TYPEOF for
>   your organization, contact Salesforce.

**UPDATE**: It will become Generally Available in the [Summer 19 release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_api_soql.htm) which is supposed to deploy to production on June 14.

If you need it earlier, you'll need to open a case with Salesforce to enable it.

Comment: and it has been in Developer Preview for a _very very long time_